# scala specs2 mocking a http client response

Tags: scala, mocking, sbt, mockito, specs2

I am trying to write a unit test for a specific method which calls a REST endpoint with given inputs(url, http method, body, headers). Below is the code.

```
  def genericAPICall(uri: String, method: String, headers: Map[String, String], body: HttpEntity): APIResponse = {
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

val client = HttpClientBuilder.create.build
val request = method match {
  case "GET" => Some(new HttpGet(uri))
  case "POST" => {
    val post =  new HttpPost(uri)
    post.setEntity(body)
    Some(post)
  }
  case "PUT" => {
    val put =  new HttpPut(uri)
    put.setEntity(body)
    Some(put)
  }
  case "DELETE" => Some(new HttpDelete(uri))
  case _ =>  None
}

if (request.isDefined) {
  val actualRequest = request.get

  if (headers.nonEmpty) {
    for ((headerName,headerVal) <- headers) {
      actualRequest.addHeader(headerName,headerVal)
    }
  } else {
    actualRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    actualRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  }


  val response: CloseableHttpResponse = null
  try {

    val response = client.execute(actualRequest)

    val entity = response.getEntity
    // use org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils to read json as string
    val str = EntityUtils.toString(entity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    APIResponse(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode(), str, null)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => APIResponse(500, null, e)
  }finally {
    if (response != null)
      response.close()
  }
} else {
  APIResponse(500, null, new Exception("not a valid http method"))
}}
```

Is there anyway i can mock below client.execute ? so i can avoid actual call to my test url ?

> val response = client.execute(actualRequest)

i am using specs2 already in my project so it would be great if anybody knows how to achieve this using specs2.

Comment: What are you trying to test, the class that makes the call or the class that serves the API?

Comment: I am trying to write unit test for above method "genericAPICall" which actually calls   REST API. I dont want my unit test triggers actual REST API call so i want to mock the API response.

Comment: Ok, that's easy, but I'd need to see where `client` comes from, could you post a little bit more of that class? also please post the test you'd like to write (even if it doesn't work)

Comment: [Don't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own)